# while loop for fetching data from array is not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sub_id=$_POST['sub_id'];
$sql_unit_list="select link_id,unit,file_name from links where sub_id='$sub_id'";
$res_unit_list=mysql_query($sql_unit_list);

if($res_unit_list)
{

    while($data_list=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql_unit_list)))
    {
        echo $data_list[0];
    }

}
```

i have written this code, i am not able to find out why the while loop is not working. it is executing the if{...} but the while loop inside the "if" is not working

Comment: `var_dump($data_list);` and see what you aregetting..

Comment: Have you run the query manually in the phpmyadmin wizard? Whether it throw some records?

Comment: yup the query is fine

Answer (score 0):

change your code with the below code,

```
$sub_id=$_POST['sub_id'];
$sql_unit_list="select link_id,unit,file_name from links where sub_id='$sub_id'";
$res_unit_list=mysql_query($sql_unit_list);

if($res_unit_list)
{

    while($data_list=mysql_fetch_array($res_unit_list))
    {
        echo $data_list[0];
    }

}
```

hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to do this way?

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM TABLE";
  $result = mysql_query($sql)
  if($result == true){
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $rows[0];//single row
     }
   }
```

OR instead mysql_fetch_array put mysql_fetch_assoc [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php%20LINK)

Answer (score 0):

you repeat the query. Instead you should use the result itself.

```
while($data_list=mysql_fetch_array($res_unit_list)){...
```

If it won't work try those two things:
1) Echo a test in the while-loop and see what happens.
2) execute the sql-statment manualy and see if you get rows or not.

Beside all that you use old mysql-functions that are outdated. You should have a look into newer (and safer) functions like mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 0):

Code syntax is incorrect

Try this

```
$sub_id=$_POST['sub_id'];
$sql_unit_list="select link_id,unit,file_name from links where sub_id='$sub_id'";
$res_unit_list=mysql_query($sql_unit_list);

if($res_unit_list)
{

    while($data_list=mysql_fetch_array($res_unit_list))
    {
        echo $data_list[0];
    }

}
```